# Memory allocation in Java

Tags: java

Explain the memory allocation in Java for a written program.

Comment: You will need to be more specific than this.

Comment: You need to be a little more explicit. What aspect of memory allocation do you want to know about?

Answer (score 6):

In general, memory is allocated on the [Java "heap"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#Heap) as an automatic result of objects being created. It's automatically managed; once an object is no longer referenced, eventually the garbage collector returns the memory it once occupied to the available pool. More info is available on the java.sun.com site, such as in this [overview of memory management](http://java.sun.com/docs/white/langenv/Simple.doc1.html#2333). Specifically as it relates to Sun's JVM implementation HotSpot, there's a [PDF on it](http://java.sun.com/j2se/reference/whitepapers/memorymanagement_whitepaper.pdf).

This is in contrast to languages (such as C) where you the programmer are in direct control of allocation and release. In Java, you just happily leave it up to the environment:

```
void doSomething() {
    NiftyObject joe;

    joe = new NiftyObject(); // Allocation

    // ...use joe for something...

    // Done; no "free" call (or similar) required
}
```

When `joe` goes out of scope (the function returns; I'm assuming here the function doesn't return `joe` or store it somewhere), `joe` *can be* collected by the garbage collector. When this actually *happens* is entirely implementation- and environment-dependent.

Comment: Just to add, there's a good article about the garbage collector here: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-1996/jw-08-gc.html

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Despite being very old (1996), the concepts and such are still valid. If he gets into any specifics (and he says he won't on the first page), they should be taken with a bit ol' grain of salt on the assumption things have moved on. But from skimming the beginning, looks good.